# Sum across all NaNs in pandas returns zero?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum across columns of a Pandas dataframe, and when I have NaNs in every column I'm getting sum = zero; I'd expected sum = NaN based on the docs. Here's what I've got:

```
In [136]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [137]: df['a'] = [1,2,np.nan,3]

In [138]: df['b'] = [4,5,np.nan,6]

In [139]: df
Out[139]: 
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2 NaN NaN
3   3   6

In [140]: df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)

In [141]: df
Out[141]: 
    a   b  total
0   1   4      5
1   2   5      7
2 NaN NaN      0
3   3   6      9
```

The pandas.DataFrame.sum docs say "If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA", so I don't understand why "total" = 0 and not NaN for index 2. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI I get NaN as expected (0.17.0.)

Comment: Thanks for the input . . . I'm running 0.17.0 as well, so this is even more puzzling.

Comment: TBH this is starting to feel more like a bug report-- I was about to suggest looking at `pd.show_versions()`, but those fit better on github than on SO. :-)

Comment: Perhaps it's the numpy version. +1 to posting this on github :)

Comment: newer numpy and/or newer bottleneck will do this. I am actually in favor using the pandas default.

Comment: discussion is here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9422

Answer (score 32):

[pandas documentation » API Reference » DataFrame » pandas.DataFrame »](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

> DataFrame.sum(self, axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, min_count=0, **kwargs)
>
> **min_count: int, default 0**
>
> The required number of valid values to
> perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are
> present the result will be NA.
>
> New in version 0.22.0: Added with the default being 0. This means the
> sum of an all-NA or empty Series is 0, and the product of an all-NA or
> empty Series is 1.

Quoting from pandas latest docs it says the `min_count` will be 0 for the all-NA series.

If you say `min_count=1` then the result of the sum will be a `NaN`.

Answer (score 11):

Great link provided by Jeff.

Here you can find a example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(); 
df1['a'] = [1,2,np.nan,3];
df1['b'] = [np.nan,2,np.nan,3]

df1
Out[4]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  3.0  3.0


df1.sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
Out[6]: 
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    6.0
dtype: float64

df1.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)
Out[7]: 
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    0.0
3    6.0
dtype: float64

df1.sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
Out[7]: 
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to select all cases where rows are all-nan, then set the sum to nan:

```
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)    
df.loc[df['a'].isnull() & df['b'].isnull(),'total']=np.nan
```

or

```
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)    
df.loc[df[['a','b']].isnull().all(1),'total']=np.nan
```

The latter option is probably more practical, because you can create a list of columns `['a','b', ... , 'z']` which you may want to sum.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by casting the series to a numpy array, which computes the answer correctly.

```
print(np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]).sum()) # nan
print(pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]).sum()) # 0.0
print(pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]).to_numpy().sum()) # nan
```