# In resampling in Pandas: How do I get NaN when all values are NaN, but still use skipna=True?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am using:

```
df_monthly = df_daily.resample('MS').agg(pd.Series.sum, skipna=True)
```

I want to skip `NaN`, but in months were all daily values is NaN I want `df_monthly` to be `NaN` and not 0. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use the parameter min_count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448003/sum-across-all-nans-in-pandas-returns-zero) in a new function sum_with_mincount. Note the brackets [ ] around sum_with_mincount. Without the brackets pandas does not know how to interpret the agg parameter skipna. This leads, unfortunately, to a multiIndex, which you need to flatten with the last line of code.

Minimal example:

```
idx = pd.date_range(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 3, 31), freq='D')
df_daily = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=idx, columns=['A', 'B'])

def sum_with_mincount(x): return x.sum(min_count=1)    
df_monthly = df_daily.resample('MS').agg([sum_with_mincount], skipna=True)
df_monthly.columns = [col[0] for col in df_monthly.columns]
```

Output:

```
            A       B
2020-01-01  nan     nan
2020-02-01  nan     nan
2020-03-01  nan     nan
```