# How to calculate a yearly sum xarray from a monthly means masked array?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to calculate the yearly sum of daily mean temperatures which are above 7 and below 33 degrees celsius. This is a customized calculation for biologically relevant degree days index. I want to do this calculation in python and I want to do it in a pythonic way, meaning, using already made functions from well known packages such xarray and numpy.

I am using the [TG dataset from CDS](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-agroclimatic-indicators?tab=overview). It is in netCDF format and it spans from 1981 to 2010.
I am stuck doing this calculation. I was able to resample the dataset into monthly mean using the following command:

```
monmean = ds.TG.resample({"time":"1MS"}).mean()
```

Now I need to do the aforementioned yearly sum of the monthly means of daily temperature means, but I can't find a way to avoid adding those values that are outside the interval that I defined. I tried to apply a mask like this:

```
masked_array = ma.masked_outside(monmean, 7+273.15, 33+273.15)
masked_monmean = np.ma.masked_where(np.ma.get_mask(masked_array), monmean)
```

But then what happens is masked_monmean is a maskedarray and the xarray function `resample` no longer applies.

```
ymonmeansum = masked_monmean.data.resample({'time':'YS'}).sum()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'resample'
```

Do you have an idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: In the third code block it should be 

ymonmeansum = masked_monmean.resample({'time':'YS'}).sum()

AttributeError: 'MaskedArray' object has no attribute 'resample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `where` method before `resample` :

```
mask = ds['TG'].isel(time=0)
ds['TG'].where(7.<=ds['TG']).where(ds['TG']<=33.).resample(time='M').mean().where(mask)
```

The `where` sets to nan the values that do not satisfy you boolean equation, and the mean excludes the nan values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing with .where is that it replaces nan values with zero and I don't know how to avoid that as well. Do you know?

Comment: I believe `where` does not replace values with zeros. You can try to plot the time serie of one mesh to make sure of it : `ds['TG'].where(7.<=ds['TG']).where(ds['TG']<=33.).isel(lon=0, lat=0).plot()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is doing so. Check it out:

<xarray.DataArray 'TG' (time: 30, lat: 360, lon: 720)>
array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],
...

Comment: This is after I did:

yearlysum = monmean.where(7.+273.15 >= monmean).where(monmean <= 33.+273.15).resample({'time':'YS'}).sum()

Comment: Can you plot one time stamp of your result ? And are you sure that in all your meshes you have at least one value >=7 and <=33. If it not the case, it's normal for those meshes to be set at 0 after the resample.

Comment: I did plot a time stamp for the first year, and comparing with the original dataset, the oceans are now purple (zero value) whereas before they were white (nan value). Over the continents you have nice colour gradients, meaning the calculation was successful and that there were values within the interval I defined.

Comment: I didn't know your dataset was masked. See my edit to my answer to have a nicely masked resampled dataset over the oceans.

Comment: Do you mean the nan values in a dataset are considered a mask? Could you explain your edit, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237289/discussion-between-cyril-and-flipad).

Comment: The zero values problem is solved if I introduce min_count=1 into sum(), like this:

yearlysum = monmean.where(7.+273.15 >= monmean).where(monmean <= 33.+273.15).resample({'time':'YS'}).sum(min_count=1)

Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448003/sum-across-all-nans-in-pandas-returns-zero