# Does pandas current treatment of missing values have potential to cause serious problems in safety-critical software?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am new to Python and pandas and have just learned that pandas silently replaces `NaN` values with 0 when calculating sums, in contrast to explicit calculations as shown here:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

np.NaN + np.NaN                              # Result: nan
pd.DataFrame([np.NaN,np.NaN]).sum().item()   # Result: 0.0
```

I think this has the potential to create hidden problems in data analyses by masking erroneous results, and am concerned about what the consequences may be in safety-critical or high-consequence applications. Furthermore, [NaN has a specific meaning in the IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) to indicate indeterminate results, not the absence of a value.

I appreciate that [pandas' Descriptive Statistics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=skipna#descriptive-statistics) methods have a `skipna` argument. However, `skipna` is by default `True`, thereby masking the presence of missing values to casual users and novice programmers... and perhaps others.

Does this have the potential to cause problems in safety-critical software or high-stakes data analyses?

Comment: Personally, I would be horrified to find that anyone is using Python for safety-critical software. But maybe that's just me. There are certainly many more potential issues than just pandas silently converting NaN to 0. Perhaps you could argue that any engineer working on safety-critical systems should have the experience and knowledge to avoid these things. And important code of any sort should be subjected to proper testing, which would definitely catch something like this. Still seems iffy to me though.

Comment: Check out [Sum across all NaNs in pandas returns zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448003/sum-across-all-nans-in-pandas-returns-zero/56982952#56982952)

Comment: I don't see this as the problem. It is indeed the expected/designed behavior. The function has `skipna` option, which defaults to `True`. If you don't want to skip `NaN` value(s), you should pass `skipna=False`.

Comment: It is indeed the designed behaviour @QuangHoang. My concern is that it is not a good design decision because the default hides a potential problem. I'd be a little less concerned if the default was `skipna=False`.

Comment: IMO, Pandas is a statistical/data-manipulation lib, NOT a security lib. It makes sense to ignore NaN values when performing statistical operations. Whether or not it's a security hole is based on the user, even more so when the option is there.

Comment: @QuangHoang Security isn't the same as safety. You want to be able to safely manipulate data (and statistics), so you can trust the library to do the right thing and to get the results you expect.

Comment: I've just revised the question to better explain my concern about this design decision causing problems in high-stakes data analyses, not just situations where safety is  at stake.

Comment: @AKX the question here is what the right thing is. Statistically, `NaN` should not be included in `mean`, `sum`, `std`, etc. And Pandas *is* a statistical library so that behavior is default. That is not to mention, the behavior is documented, the one uses the library is responsible for the behavior. If the engineer did not understand the intended behavior of the function/lib they use, it's the engineer's false, not the library. Again, the library is designed for *statistical/data-manipulation* purposes.

Comment: @QuangHoang You could say all programs are designed for data-manipulation purposes. I'd argue Pandas' defaults are bad if it can hide mistakes like this; `na="raise"`/`na="skip"`/`na="zero"` (or similar) would be a better design, with `na="raise"` being the default. Explicit Is Better Than Implicit and all...

Comment: Anyway, I kind of share @DavidLovell's concern here: who knows how many analyses are quietly, accidentally wrong since their Pandas operators haven't used the correct `skipna`?

Comment: Again, his question relates to *data analyses*, which means `skipna=True` is correct option.